# printing from jquery mobile (phonegap) application in android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, printing, cordova

I have an android application developed with jquery mobile, html5 and css3.

I create the apk with "phonegap build" and installed on my android tablet.

I simply need to print an html page from my application.

In windows I use window.print javascript native function or a jquery plugin like "PrintArea".

Are there some ways to send the input at the android os?

I have already installed printhand and printshare on my tablet and it works on local printer.

I just need to print with this printer from my application.

Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I also have this problem. Could anyone please give an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is a solution for this.
there is a plugin to print with a large amount of third party applications.

You might find this [Phonegap printer plugin](https://github.com/EionRobb/phonegap-print-plugins) useful.